# Frequent BSODs on Windows laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, battery, bsod, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently had frequent BSOD on my Windows system. These were mostly when on battery. So I started using always plugged in. But today, I got BSOD when on battery when running `docker build .` command inside WSL.

These are some sceenshots of event viewer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What might have gone wrong here? How can I avoid BSODs?

PS: I am running Windows 10 and have very 18 GB of free disk space in C drive and have 16 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

1. Some laptop mains power supplies cannot handle full load when performing intensive work with CPU and/or GPU, and rely on the battery to "buffer" the power. Check the battery condition:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Enter the following: `powercfg /batteryreport` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a *Battery report*.
- Open the report, typically at *C:\Windows\System32\battery-report.html*.

[image: Battery report]

If the *FULL CHARGE CAPACITY* is much below *DESIGN CAPACITY*, then the battery likely needs to be replaced.

2. The issue could also be due to overheating; check CPU and GPU temperature with a free tool such as [HWinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) while the system is under load.

For *both* scenarios, you can exercise the processors with a free tool such as [HeavyLoad](https://www.jam-software.com/heavyload).

Before using or installing any software, it's a good idea to check it at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload).